# PHP file-based notebook

Tags: web-apps, php, note-taking

I am looking for a tiny PHP script which allows web-based note taking.

I do not want a database, so notes should be stored in files. I even do not need a hierarchy.

One PHP file would be great but the actual premise is no database. It should be installed on a plugPC with limited disk space. So less than 300kb would be good.

Maybe it’s too simple for anybody to bother to upload and provide such a trivial tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using [FileThingie](http://www.solitude.dk/filethingie/) (which is a PHP file browser with integrated editor) and pointed it to an empty directory. For each note I now have to create a new file. Not very comfortable (because many clicks are necessary for creating and editing notes) and quite heavy (~2MB), but it works.

Comment: Don't forget to accept your own answer (the system will allow it after 2 days), to help others who search for this in future.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly small, but it saves into plain text, and keeps revisions, so it might be of use - see `SPNoter` in this answer:

- [Online note taking with Markdown and revisions (saved in server filesystem)?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/25527/online-note-taking-with-markdown-and-revisions-saved-in-server-filesystem/32033#32033)