# Web-based note taking software

Tags: php, note-taking, self-hosted, markdown

Can anyone recommend a web-based note taking software?

- Free.
- Self hosted.
- saves to flatfiles (.md ideally so markdown capable).
- Visually well designed and interface pleasant to use.
- ideally made with php so I can modify if need be but open to other languages.

I've already looked at these:
[Online note taking with Markdown and revisions (saved in server filesystem)?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/25527/online-note-taking-with-markdown-and-revisions-saved-in-server-filesystem/32033#32033)

The two that come closest to what I'm looking for are Laverna (the dropbox feature does not seem to work and browser storage is a bad idea) and Standardnotes (can't self host and saves to json).

Comment: Why is web-based a criteria?

Comment: Self-hosted, cross device, cross-platform, one solution for all, able to modify if needed, tired of app versions and compatibility, etc. etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spent several days evaluating different solutions.

These were what I tested and the stand out solutions - may be useful to somebody.  These were the best:

- Laverna - https://laverna.cc/
- DokuWiki - https://www.dokuwiki.org/dokuwiki#
- Standard Notes - https://app.standardnotes.org/
- Simplenote - https://simplenote.com/
- TiddlyWiki - http://tiddlywiki.com/

Then in no particular order:

- Paperwork - http://paperwork.rocks/
- Marknote - https://github.com/WuSiYu/MarkNote
- Nimblenotes - https://nimblenotes.com/

Comment: Polynote - https://polynote.io/
Ownnote - https://github.com/Fmstrat/ownnote
PmWiki - http://www.pmwiki.org/wiki
Alternote - http://alternoteapp.com/
Boostnote - https://boostnote.io/
Collate - https://collatenotes.com/
Falcon - http://falcon.star-lord.me/
Elephant - http://elephant.mine.nu/
Markdownnotes - http://markdownnotes.com/
Mendeley - https://www.mendeley.com/
Milanote - https://www.milanote.com/
Notebooks - http://www.notebooksapp.com/
Opennote - https://github.com/FoxUSA/OpenNote
QOwnNotes - http://www.qownnotes.org/
Syncnotes - http://www.qrayon.com/home/syncnotes/

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into [Tiddlywiki](http://tiddlywiki.com/)?

It is a self contained note taking application in a single html file.

It does not use php or require any servers and is written in javascript + html + css.
It can run standalone in a web browser, or be [installed in a Node.js](http://tiddlywiki.com/#Installing%20TiddlyWiki%20on%20Node.js) instance.

Standalone saves files within itself, in a server they are written to file-system, as flatfiles in either local Wikitext dialect or markdown optionally markdown flavor.

It can be used for much more than that. With scripting and customization it can be extended and become almost any sort of web application, formatting and automating lots of tasks.

Comment: Yes I did, very quickly.  I wasn't keen on the long blog like scroll but I spent some more time with it and I can see that can be turned off.  Saving within the html is a definite no for me - it has to be flatfiles.  Unclear how the flatfile option works, is that only via node.js?

Comment: Yes separate flat files are only available in the node.js server version, though you can jump freely between the two by importing and exporting, as far as I know. Never used the server version myself though, not sure. I think single file version also partially supports external content as flat files, you edit them externally, and the content is probably not directly searchable.

Comment: That's a shame.  Seems I can't install node.js on my server so it rules out Tiddywiki unless I modify it.  Apart from that it's quite good.